# How To Put Image on Panel in Adobe Flash?

Tags: android, flash

i have created one dashboard for android in adobe flash4.5 now i want to put Background_image on one of the panel.can any one please give me idea how to put image on background screen of panel?

Thanks in Advance----

Answer (score 0):

If your panels are movieClips , then edit the movie clips and place an image loader at the bottom most layer of the movieClip.
By handling the instance of that loader , you can dynamically change the images which could be a random background images.